# Find and replace all occurrences of a tag in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am trying to find and replace all occurences of a tag `<xyz..ewwef>` in a text using Python or Notepad++.

Since I got a lot of data, Python keeps hanging up when I use the regex function, so I'd prefer using Notepad++.

But the < and > seem to mess up the search syntax, so if I try finding all `<>` plus their content in between using `(?=<).*(?=>)`, Notepad is not able to find any matches.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Xavier! Check your formatting please. Tags like `<>` are stripped out from posts for reasons of HTML sanitizing. You need to wrap them in code blocks by using backticks: `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `[?=<].*[?=>]` in notepad++. `<.*>` also works.

For processing regex on large files in Python, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4893506/114147), and [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5559536/114147), and [this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/454456/114147).

Comment: That did the trick. Silly me. Thanks.
But now I got a different problem. The text starts with an `<I>` and ends in `</I>` so it is about to replace the whole thing :(

Comment: So in this case you do _not_ want to find `<>` plus their content? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/787932/114147) for a link to the HTML Agility pack, for processing these kind of things :)

Comment: I guess I made it now. I figured out the tags in use and included them specifically into the `<>`but one argument of them always starts in ICE but is followed to running numbers. What is the most elegant way to match all those `<>` when content starts in "ICE"?

Comment: `<ICE.*>` seems to find those cases that starts in "ICE", including the surrounding brackets.

Comment: For interest, regex questions loosely fall into programming, such Q's go well on [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) :)